# Flutter - setting width to a TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I want a TextFormField with specific width - let's say a small one of 70 pixels - I need to wrap it in a Container with a "width" property. But if I do it this way, the error text (in case the field doesn't pass validation) will also be constrained in this fixed-width Container. I want to let the error text spread all over the screen width even if I make the field itself narrower. Is it possible? Does TextFormField has some sort of a "width" property or does anybody know of a workaround? It feels like a pretty basic requirement.

```
Container(
  width: 70,
  child: TextFormField(
    ...
    decoration: // Just a custom input decoration...
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.length != 3) {
        return '3 digits required.';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
);
```

[image: This is how it looks if I wrap the TextFormField in a fixed-width Container]

Answer (score 1):

You can display your own error text in separate container with full width.

Firstly store a new variable in `State` class.

```dart
String _errorMessage = null;
```

And in your render method update value inside validator, and pass value to if condition to show/hide error message.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      width: 70,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          String setError(String msg) {
            if (_errorMessage != msg) {
              setState(() { _errorMessage = msg; });
            }
            return msg;
          }

          if (value.length != 3) {
            return setError('3 digits required.');
          }

          return setError(null);
        },
      ),
    ),
    if (_errorMessage != null)
    Text(_errorMessage, style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
    )),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the width of the `TextFormField` use a `SizedBox()`. If you want to spread the error message all over the screen use a `Column()` with a `TextFormField()` and a `Text()` Widget. You can use

```
Container( 
width: 100
height: 20
child:
    FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: Text('test text'),
    )
)
```

to size the text in relation to its parent Widget.

Comment: Code example doesn't include TextFormField